# google hangout api widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-api, google-hangouts

I have a problem with my widget: I have the following code in order to catch when a user close the windows o leave the call:

```
window.onunload = function() {
            if (participants.length = 1 ){
                console.log("Frist User Leaving the room");
                    $.ajax({
                  url: "https://pre.blabloo.com/hangout_ending_1to1_class.json",
                  data: {"url" : hangOutUrl, "participants" : params},
                  dataType: 'jsonp',
                  success: function(){
                    console.log("Ending class");
                  },
                  error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                      console.log("Impossible to connect");
                      console.log(xhr.statusText);
                      console.log(textStatus);
                      console.log(error);
                  }
                });
           } else {
                console.log("Second User Leaving the room");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "https://pre.blabloo.com/hangout_ending_1to1_class_last_user.json",
                    data: {"url" : hangOutUrl, "participants" : params},
                    dataType: 'jsonp',
                    success: function(){
                        console.log("Ending class");
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
                        /*console.log("Impossible to connect");
                        console.log(xhr.statusText);
                        console.log(textStatus);
                        console.log(error);*/
                    }
                });
            }

    }
```

This code does not work, BUT if I use the developer tools of my browser and make a breakpoint a run this code step by step it works. What can I do. Please a really need help I have two days with this issues.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?